# using the word "croesus"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I came across the word croesus a long back but pondered over its usage recently. It has the two following definitions: 
1. the last king of Lydia
2. a wealthy person

Is it correct, formally, to say that he is a croesus when I mean he is wealthy and filthy rich or rather I should say that he is like croesus?

My friends dissent such a usage so I got bemused.. Please help.

Comment: Capitalization of proper names is important.

Comment: The story of the king Croesus is over 2000 years old. To use such things in everyday language can be curious. Not everybody knows about Croesus. And someone might ask "Who is Croesus?".

Comment: In the amount of time it took me to scroll down this far, I've forgotten where OP's definition said Croesus was king of. For the purposes of *English*, you don't need to know anything except that he was very rich (richer than even [Midas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midas), for all I know or care). And we only normally say *"He's **as rich as** Croesus"*, not *"He's [a] Croesus"* - so even if you forget that one little "factoid", you'll probably be reminded of it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a virtually non-existent metaphoric usage (i.e. - **metaphorically** using unqualified *Croesus* to mean *a rich man*, rather than the standard **simile** usage *as rich as Croesus*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase you are looking for is:

> As rich as Croesus.

It comes from the legend of the excessively wealthy king Croesus who is said to have so much gold that he had every guest take as much gold as he could carry, upon leaving. One fellow asked Croesus if he could take his gold at a later date, to which Croesus assented. The man return a few weeks later with a coat that was covered with pockets inside and out. Not only this, but his body and the hair on his head was greased. He went into the treasury of Croesus where he disrobed and rolled in gold dust so that he was gilded from head to toe He filled all the pockets of his coat with coins and nuggets. He even filled his mouth with coins. His load was so cumbersom that he could barely move. Croesus thought this site hilarious. Though a tad poorer after this episode, Croesus was still a very rich King.

Source [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Croesus), [Phrase.co.uk](http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/15/messages/193.html), [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/rich+as+croesus)

---

The phrase is usually used for someone who has immense amounts of wealth; used for someone with near limitless fortune.

Example of possible usage.

- Person 1: Hey, did you hear about Billy?
- Person 2: Yeah, heard his business really took off.
- Person 1: Made a whopping off that last deal! He's as rich a Croesus.

Comment: does it mean "he is a croesus" is incorrect? The dictionary is so damn confusing.

Comment: @vickyace The phrase is 'As Rich as Croesus'. I've amended my answer with an example. No, 'he is a Croesus' is incorrect, but I suppose that it still gets the message across.

Comment: It's **sight** not *site*. (Once you've edited, I'll delete this comment)